# jQuery variable name appended with a large number

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I often see in my code I am loading from my company's media central that jQuery is not available in the console normally. (No `$` and `jQuery`)

But sometimes, to those elements to which jQuery is attached, it has a long number with it.

```
jQuery18306575689211022109_1378907534666
```

What is the purpose of doing this? Security?

Also, jQuery is sometimes available directly in the console, but only with the above numbers.
I am therefore unable to debug my apps in console, where I need to query using jQuery.

However, in the JavaScript code, jQuery is perfectly being used as `$` and `jQuery`. So I apply a break-point and export as `window.jQuery = jQuery`.

Is this a proper way to debug the app, when `jQuery` is obfuscated?

**UPDATE**:

For eg., check this [**URL**](http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?format=json&url=http%3A//fmarier.org&callback=jQuery18306575689211022109_1378907534666&_=1378907534854) the app is calling. It seems that the URL knows what is the number appended to jQuery. How do I come to know of the same number while debugging? Any lights on what is going on?

Comment: What's your company's "media central"?

Comment: The CDN repository from which common code like `jQuery`, Twitter Bootsrap, etc. is loaded. This architecture is followed in almost all Web companies.

Comment: Looks like a `AJAX callback id`.

Comment: This is a callback id used in JSONp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing two different variables. You can make a quick test on this website : http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/jsonp/#demo. Click "run demo", open Chrome's console, type "jQuery" in order to retrieve the callback's name, then perform this simple comparison :

```
jQuery16409391013463027775_1379048051365 === jQuery // false
```

That said, the fact that the variables named "$" and "jQuery" are not available in your case may be due to a specific implementation. One possibility could be the use of [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which allows either to customize the name used as a reference to jQuery, or to completely remove all references to jQuery from the global scope (`window`), so there is no way to access it in the console.

Comment: `completely remove all references to jQuery from the global scope` ? How is that done using `noConflict`? Also, I understand that this is for `jsonp`. But `jQuery16409...` is available in my `console`, and not `jQuery` or `$`

Comment: Copy and paste this code into your browser's console : `function noConflict(){ a = undefined; }; var a = 1; console.log('a = ' + a); noConflict(); console.log('a = ' + a);`. This is done in a similar way with jQuery. That said, the documentation is more useful to understand this kind of concept. Click on the links I have left in the answer for better explanations.

Comment: AFAIK, jQuery `noConflict` API doesn't say it removes references to `jQuery`, but only `$`. Or at least some version of `jQuery` has also been loaded on the page which has its own `$` or `jQuery` literal. IN both cases, my console should show either `jQuery` or `$`

Comment: @OmShankar Read better : "removeAll. Type: Boolean. A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the global scope (including jQuery itself).". However, I have exposed this idea only as a possibility, you'll have to produce a little effort to check whether I'm right or wrong. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

It's a callback id automatically generated by jQuery. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for `jsonpCallback`.

> It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling.

Comment: Why `jQuery` is not available in the console normally?

Comment: @OmShankar, to be honest I didn't really understand that part of the question. `jQuery18306575689211022109_1378907534666&_=1378907534854` _isn't_ jQuery, it's just an id parameter jQuery uses for the callback.

Comment: I got it. I am just asking that why is jQuery not available as `jQuery` when I open the console. In the console too, it is available with numbers attached to it.  

May be the resulting JavaScript executes the callback in `window`'s scope replacing the original jQuery variable??

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer, thanks!